# How do I disable telnet on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: telnet

I installed Ubuntu server and I am learning to how secure it.

One of the article I saw, was about telnet and how to disable it on CentOS

Obviously, it does not work on Ubuntu, so How can I disable Telnet on Ubuntu server?

```
ll /etc/xinetd.d/telnet
ls: cannot access /etc/xinetd.d/telnet: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu has a [no open ports](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies#No_Open_Ports) policy which covers the default installation.

The instructions do not work because telnet is not enabled on Ubuntu Server. You do not need to disable telnet unless you've installed a telnet daemon on your own and enabled it.